# it shows multiple validation errors instead one in codeigniter3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I wrote a code that shows validation errors with Ajax in the codeigniter3 framework. But, after pressing submit button multiple times, it shows error messages many times[image: errors] but, I want it to show the error ones. Also, it does not show any error after textarea despite, İ removed CKEditor it also didn't show the error. [image: noerrors]How can I solve these issues?

Here is my view:

```
<div id="messages"></div>

        <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'continueregistrationform', 'id' => 'continueregistrationform'); ?>
                  <?= form_open_multipart('user/submit', $attributes); ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">


                  <div class="row">
                    <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="name" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?= $instructors['name']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="web" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="web" placeholder="Web-site" value="<?= $instructors['web']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                   </div> 

                   <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="tel" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" value="<?= $instructors['phone']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="address" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?= $instructors['address']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                 </div>   
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="facebook" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" value="<?= $instructors['fb']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="twitter" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" value="<?= $instructors['twitter']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="youtube" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="youtube" placeholder="Youtube" value="<?= $instructors['youtube']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div id="instagram" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram" value="<?= $instructors['instagram']; ?>">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                  </div> 


                 <div class="row">
                    <div id="profiledesc" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12 input-group" >
                            <textarea name="insdescription"  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description"><?= $instructors['description']; ?></textarea>
                        </div><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('profiledesc');
                    </script>
                  </div>



                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="modal-footer btncolor">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="rex-bottom-medium rex-btn-icon">
                        <span class="rex-btn-text">Submit</span>
                        <span class="rex-btn-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></span>
                    </button>  
                  </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Here is my ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#continueregistrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);


        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);              
                if(response.success) {                  
                    $("#messages").html(response.messages);
                    $("#continueregistrationform")[0].reset();
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                    location.href = "http://localhost/edu-center/";

                }
                else {
                    $("#messages").html(response.messages);

                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                        var element = $("#"+index);

                        $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        $(element).after(value);

                    });
                }
            } // /success
        });  // /ajax

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: please post your controller

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Za9y4Tt6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your jquery code to following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('insdescription1');
$("#continueregistrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);

    // Check value of textarea and ckeditor before submit
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);              
            if(response.success) {                  
                $("#messages").html(response.messages);
                $("#continueregistrationform")[0].reset();
                $(".text-danger").remove();
                $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                location.href = "http://localhost/edu-center/";

            }
            else {
                $("#messages").html(response.messages);
                $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                    var element = $("#"+index);
        $(element).parent('div').find('.text-danger').remove();
                    $(element).after(value);

                });
            }
        } // /success
    });  // /ajax

    return false;
});
```

});

For insdescription or CKEDITOR validation replace small part of your view file code as follow

Change

```
<div id="profiledesc" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12 input-group" >
                            <textarea name="insdescription"  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                        </div><br><br>
                    </div>
```

To

```
<div id="insdescription" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 input-group" >
        <textarea name="insdescription" id="insdescription1"  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    </div><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked great! But.... because of CKEditor, when I type smth in inputs and press submit button, the validation errors disappear, but in textarea, it was not. However I removed CKEditor, it worked properly

Comment: Give unique id to textarea and check its value before submit, i have updated my answer.

Comment: it is very interesting :D it worked, but if I insert 1 character, it does not throw an error :D

Comment: because html tags were added to it, add another rule to escape html tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to force **CKeditor** to update the textarea value using:

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

Use like this:

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
function saveData() 
{
    // You must need to add this code to update the ckeditor
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save_data.php',
        data: $("#formId").serialize()
     });  
     return false; 
 }
```

Comment: add this line of code:  for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
after this line in your script var form = $(this);

Comment: İ added the first code, it did not help

https://yadi.sk/i/uaWTYZ7a3LY39K